# Add string to a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have function `addNumber` and if I click on button with specific value, the value is concatenate to variable b. But if the value of "a" is other than number, the function doesn't work. What am I missing? I thought that the function works with parameter "a" as if it was a string. Otherwise the number were add up. So if `b=0`, `a=x`; the result of `b=b+a` will be `x`.

```
function addNumber(a) {
    b=b+a;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= b;
}
```

I think that problem is here.

```
function addNumber(a) {

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= String(a);
}
```

If the parameter "a" is number, it returns number, but if the parameter "a" is equals some string, returns nothing. 
Why?

Comment: `b = parseInt(b) ? b + a : a`

Comment: isn't it supposed to add the number?

Comment: are you using parseInt to convert in to a number?

Comment: But what exactly you want. Answer these!                                                                          1. if b=10 and a=10 Result=20;                                                                        2. If b=0 and a=x Result=??                                                                        3. b=a and a= s or ss..ssss.. etc., Result=??

Comment: if b=1 and a=2 Result=12, If b=1 and a=x Result=1x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to treat both variables as strings, you could explicitly cast them as such:

```
function addNumber(a) {
    b = String(b) + String(a);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= b;
}
```

Comment: this works but what I want to do is concatenate 2 or more numbers. Im making calculator. If I click on button 1, result will be 1, if I click than on 2, the result will be 12. Now it is working but if I click for instance on comma sign, it doesn't return 12, .

Comment: Javascript is a loose type language, so nothing stop you from passing illegal types. Since you are making a calculator, you should check if the input is from 0~9 first, if it is then call addNumber if it's not then do something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add 2 numbers then you need to parse string into number before adding.
**parseInt** is used for parsing string to integer.

If its not parsed then it will be treated as string and **+** will act as concatenation operator

Comment: Yes I understand. I want to concatenate numbers, but sometimes I want to concatenate number with string and the function above is working good when the a parameter represent number, but if it is a string, it doesn't concatenate the number and string together as I expected.